# Add timestamp and name to modified row

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I wanted to create a new Excel worksheet with time and namestamp in every modified row.

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A3:P9999")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row() - 1, 18) = Date
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row() - 1, 17) = Environ("username")
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Without adding the `-1` to the `Cells` lines I got the stamps one line below the active (modified) cell.

I added `-1` but now when I hit the `delete` button to clear that cell, I've stamps one line above the active cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Target` (the changed cell), rather than `ActiveCell`. After you have finished editing a cell, by default you will end up in the cell below so that will be active.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A3:P9999")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

With Target
    Cells(.Row, 18) = Date
    Cells(.Row, 17) = Environ("username")
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```